# Boot partition was unmounted during kernel update

Tags: arch-linux, kernel

So, I updated the kernel from 3.18.5-Arch to 3.18.6 and without mounting my boot partition. Now, no usb device (vfat not recognized) can be mounted and no network connection (no interface except lo) is currently possible? What should i do now?

Comment: Mount `/boot` and reinstall the kernel and rebuild the initrd..

Comment: That is a separate question... Include details of your card, driver and journal output.